# Vue : Updating deep dosn't trigger re-rendering

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

Im having an array that looks something like this:

```
customers : [ {customer : 'foo', address : {postalCode : 6655, city : 'somewhere'}}, ..
]
```

I render a list something like this :

```
<template v-for="(cust, inx) in customers">
<div>{{ customers[inx].customer }}</div>
<div>{{customers[inx].address.postalCode }}|{{ customers[inx].address.city}}</div>
</template>
```

Now I have a function that gets the city when people enters a new postalcode it fetches a city and sets it with :

```
this.$set(self.customers[inx].address, 'city', 'NewCityName');
```

The thing is, I can confirm that the text is actually changed in the correct object, but it doesnt trigger a re-rendering.
Am I using the $set function in a wrong way in this case?

Comment: If the `city` property already exists inside the relevant object then using `$set` won't be any different to setting it directly using `self.customers[inx].address.city = 'NewCityName'`. Based on the code you've provided I believe it should trigger a re-rendering, so you may need to put together a [mcve] so we can see the problem ourselves. If the `city` property is initially missing and is being populated without `$set` elsewhere then that might explain what is going on. Unrelated to your problem but in your template you keep writing `customers[inx]` when you could just write `cust`.

Comment: You should also add `:key="inx"` not doing so can cause re-rendering issues. And why are you using `this` and `self`? Alternatively to figure out what properties are not reactive console log the object and check what properties dont have getter/setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that `this.customers` is not set correctly (is not marked as oservable) i.e. not declared in data like `{customers:[]}`, or any of its items are not set correctly. If you evaluate in devtools console, it must give out for `this.customer` and any of its items something like: `{__ob__: Observer}` and in expanded view must contain an item `__ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}`. These types of errors are most annoying in vue.

Object and array elements are observed only if they exist. Array methods like `push`, `splice` are observed too, so `this.array[2] = obj` will not work if array length < 2 but `this.array.push(obj)` works as expected. In other cases `$set(...)` is necessary to mark element as observable.